# Dash loading component while files are being uploaded

Tags: plotly-dash

I've googled this question 6 ways from Sunday and surprisingly I haven't found an answer. I would like to simply show a spinner, ideally using the `dcc.Loading` component, while files are being uploaded using the `dcc.Upload` component. I can't believe this isn't an out of the box option built into the Upload component itself. My app allows users to upload multiple large files to plot so without a spinner they think the app is just frozen for a minute or more.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your question. This is why dcc.Loading is for, isn't it enough to put your plots in a dcc.Loading ?

Comment: Could you please include the code that you have tried so far. It is encouraged that questions contain a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Dash in a while, but I think you can write a [Dash callback](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks) that triggers a change in the `dcc.Loading` component when the `loading_state` property of the [dcc.Upload](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload) component changes.

Something like this:

```
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-spinner', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='my-upload', component_property='loading_state')
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return f'Output: {input_value["is_loading"]}'
```